# Книги по HTML5 и CSS3

Tags: html5, css3, книги

Добрый день, хочу освоить HTML5 и CSS3, подскажите книги на русском языке, если можете с сылками

Answer (score 2):

- Хольцнер С. - Освой самостоятельно HTML5 за 10 минут, 5-е издание (2011)
- Лабберс П. - HTML5 для профессионалов (2011)
- Лоусон Б., Шарп Р. - Изучаем HTML5 (2011)
- Хоган Б. - HTML5 и CSS3 (2012)
- Шмитт К. - CSS. Рецепты программирования (2009)

В последней книге есть кое-что по CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 и CSS3 Веб-разработка по стандарту нового поколения, автор Брайан Хоган.

Comment: Вы читали её сами?