# Литература по WEB-программированию

Tags: книги

Образование не из IT сферы. Решил учится самостоятельно.  с основ `HTML` и `CSS`
учил по книге - Квинт И. "HTML, XHTML и CSS на 100 %", на данный момент начал учить JavaScript.

---

Интересует литература по JavaScript и другим языкам и технологиям WEB-программирования. Подскажите в какой последовательности что учить и что читать. (просьба не давать много книг по одному и тому же на выбор - посоветуйте лучше одну которую вы считаете наиболее успешной) План по обучению который я составил для себя:

1. HTML 4.01;
2. CSS 2;
3. SSi;
4. JavaScript;
5. ООП;
6. jQuery;
7. JSon;
8. AJAX;
9. БД (MySQL);
10. PHP 5.3;
11. Zend Framework;
12. Java.

Comment: Это очень популярный вопрос.

Достаточно вбить в гугл "хорошая книга по ***" - и первые же несколько ссылок приведут вас на сайты, где специалисты в отрасли долго и кропотливо обсуждают, какая книга хорошая, а какая нет. И, как правило, пришли к какому-то консенсусу.

Comment: Кстати, осмелюсь заметить, что порядок изучения вы выбрали для себя странный. Несомненно, начинать стоит с HTML и вёрстки. Не привязываясь к версиям всяким, кстати. SSI никто не пользуется. JSON - нечего тут "изучать".. Java к Web-технологиям имеет смутное отношение, поэтому её тоже за борт.

Советую попробовать изучать в таком порядке: HTML и CSS, Jquery и нативный JS (опционально), нативный PHP и MySQL, ООП в PHP, Zend Framework и разные CMF (когда хорошо поймёте PHP).

Answer (score 2):

### PHP

- Моей первой книжкой по PHP, которая до сих пор остаётся моей настольной, не смотря на то, что местами устарела и потёрлась - была [PHP : Карманный Справочник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2644289/) Кристиана Уэнца от  изд-ва "Вильямс".
- В качестве глупой настольной книги, где можно чтонить посмотреть, я использую [книгу Колисниченко о разработке веб-приложений](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6209713/). Не ждите от неё многого, но она хороша.
- Книга Мэтта Зандстры [PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5648968/) весьма хороша для погружения глубже в ооп.
- Книга Питера Ловейна "[Объектно-ориентированное программирование на PHP5](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3452953/)" - весьма хороша своими налядными примерами. Она даёт чёткое понимание удобства ООП.

Comment: Стоит ли говорить, что в электронном виде эти книги найти не составит труда? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

- [List of freely available programming books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)
- [PHP tutorial that is security-, accuracy- and maintainability-conscious?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119083/php-tutorial-that-is-security-accuracy-and-maintainability-conscious)
- [Книги по JavaScript, HTML5, Node.JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/181589/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-javascript-html5-node-js)
- [Материал по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/162820/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%BE-php)
- [Поиск профессиональной литературы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/156580/php-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B)
- [Книги по HTML5 и CSS3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/149622/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-html5-%D0%B8-css3)

Comment: Ваш ник как нельзя лучше подходит в данной ситуации :)

Comment: вы правы...

Comment: кроме php ничего не можете посоветовать?:)

Answer (score 1):

1. Практика
2. Всё что непонятно - google / yandex

Просто Интернет технологии настолько быстро развиваются, что из книг можешь взять только основы. Всё остальное будет не актуально. Поэтому всю информацию в IT лучше брать с просторов интернета - с форумов, с сайтов веб дизайна и т.д. (ИМХО).

Единственное что, ООП можете почитать книжку, чтобы стать ближе к IT, а все остальное в процессе разработки чего-либо. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codecademy.com/ онлайн обучение